# Como uilizar DirectoryHelper en Angular?

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript

Soy nuevo en angular ,estoy intentando adaptar un codigo de C# en typescript y angular 13 pero no logro tomar el path de una carpeta de mi maquina  y guardarla en una  variable para despues poder modificar o utilizar los archivos de ese path ya que el codigo en **c#** utilizan la libreria **DirectoryHelper**
,todo lo realizo al momento de presionar un boton

El codigo que estoy tratando de adaptar es el siguiente

```
{
        string path = DirectoryHelper.OpenDialogDirectorySelector("Directory Selector", FilesPath);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            FilesPath = path;
            ConfigHelper.DirectoryPath = FilesPath;
        }
        LoadDirectory(null);
    }
```

Mi codigo es el siguiente

```
<button (click)="showDialog()">Abrir Cuadro de Diálogo</button>

<p-dialog header="Seleccionar Carpeta" [(visible)]="displayDialog">
  <p-fileUpload name="files" url="your-upload-url" (onUpload)="onFolderSelected($event)"></p-fileUpload>
  <button (click)="hideDialog()">Cancelar</button>
</p-dialog>
```

```
onFolderSelected(event: any) {

  const response = JSON.parse(event.xhr.response);
  this.selectedFolderPath = response.message;
  this.hideDialog();
}
```

Comment: No se puede. El software que se ejecuta en el navegador tiene restricciones de acceso a la máquina local.

Comment: ok, muchas gracias por la respuesta y la ayuda